# Display single category posts with OctoberCMS

Tags: routes, octobercms

I have table categories with fields - id, category.
I have table posts with fields - id, title, description.
I have pivot table with fields - category_id, post_id.

How can i create route that will show all posts from one category? I've tried:

```
Route::get('category/{id}', function($id) {
  $posts = Post::with(['image','category'])->where('category.id', $id)->get();
  return $posts;
});
```

but I get unknown column error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could solve this. I will show you the laravel way with the `whereHas` method. You can look at the documentation [here](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations#querying-relations). I have hardly used the `with` method so you might need to experiment but this is how I would do it.

```
$posts = Post::with('image')->whereHas('category', function ($category) use ($id) {
    $category->where('id', $id);
})->get();
```

Why I think your query isn't working is because your `->where('category_id', $id)` is being done directly on the Post model which doesn't have a `category_id` I bet. You don't get access to the pivot table fields from one of the relationship models. You can always look at the collection attributes by doing a die and dump; `dd($posts)`.

Also a big tip to think about in the future is create/use explicit variables. Instead of using `category/{id}` use `category/{categoryId}`. This will save you a lot of headaches in the future. It will also save a lot of headaches for people who look at your code.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should define in your `Post` model the relationship like this:

```
public $belongsToMany = [
    'categories' => [
        'Your\PLugin\Models\Category',
        'table'    => 'categories_table',
        'key'      => 'post_id',
        'otherKey' => 'category_id'
    ],
];
```

Then, you can access your categories related to the post like this:

```
$post = Post::find($post_id);
$post_categories = $post->categories;
```

Comment: Ok, i see now that you want the opposite, all Posts related to category, Just define the same belongsToMany relation but in Category. And access related posts with `$some_category->posts`, where `posts` is the name of the relationship in your `Category` model.

Comment: I have already Post model setup like so:   public $belongsToMany = [
    'category' => [
      'Amerey\Amerey\Models\Category',
      'table' => 'amerey_amerey_posts_cat',
      'order' => 'category'
    ]
  ];

Comment: and my Category model like so:     public $belongsToMany = [
      'post' => [
        'Amerey\Amerey\Models\Post',
        'table' => 'amerey_amerey_posts_cat',
        'order' => 'title'
      ]
    ];